# reading .csv file + JSON with Matlab

Tags: json, matlab, csv, dataset

So I have a .CSV file that contains dataset information, the data seems to be described in JSON. I want to read it with MatLab. One line example(7000 total) of the data:

```
imagename.jpg,"[[{""name"":""nose"",""position"":[2911.68,1537.92]},{""name"":""left eye"",""position"":[3101.76,544.32]},{""name"":""right eye"",""position"":[2488.32,544.32]},{""name"":""left ear"",""position"":null},{""name"":""right ear"",""position"":null},{""name"":""left shoulder"",""position"":null},{""name"":""right shoulder"",""position"":[190.08,1270.08]},{""name"":""left elbow"",""position"":null},{""name"":""right elbow"",""position"":[181.44,3231.36]},{""name"":""left wrist"",""position"":[2592,3093.12]},{""name"":""right wrist"",""position"":[2246.4,3965.76]},{""name"":""left hip"",""position"":[3006.72,3360.96]},{""name"":""right hip"",""position"":[155.52,3412.8]},{""name"":""left knee"",""position"":null},{""name"":""right knee"",""position"":null},{""name"":""left ankle"",""position"":[2350.08,4786.56]},{""name"":""right ankle"",""position"":[1460.16,5019.84]}]]","[[{""segment"":[[0,17.28],[933.12,5175.36],[0,5166.72],[0,2306.88]]}]]",https://imageurl.jpg,
```

If I use the Import functionlity/tool, I am able separate the data in four colums using the , as delimiter:

Image File Name,Key Points,Segmentation,Image URL,

```
imagename.jpg,

"[[{""name"":""nose"",""position"":[2911.68,1537.92]},{""name"":""left eye"",""position"":[3101.76,544.32]},{""name"":""right eye"",""position"":[2488.32,544.32]},{""name"":""left ear"",""position"":null},{""name"":""right ear"",""position"":null},{""name"":""left shoulder"",""position"":null},{""name"":""right shoulder"",""position"":[190.08,1270.08]},{""name"":""left elbow"",""position"":null},{""name"":""right elbow"",""position"":[181.44,3231.36]},{""name"":""left wrist"",""position"":[2592,3093.12]},{""name"":""right wrist"",""position"":[2246.4,3965.76]},{""name"":""left hip"",""position"":[3006.72,3360.96]},{""name"":""right hip"",""position"":[155.52,3412.8]},{""name"":""left knee"",""position"":null},{""name"":""right knee"",""position"":null},{""name"":""left ankle"",""position"":[2350.08,4786.56]},{""name"":""right ankle"",""position"":[1460.16,5019.84]}]]",

"[[{""segment"":[[0,17.28],[933.12,5175.36],[0,5166.72],[0,2306.88]]}]]",

https://imageurl.jpg,
```

But I have truble trying to use the tool to do further decomposition of the data. Of corse the ideal would be to separate the data in a code.

I hope someone can orientate me on how to or the tools I need to use. I have seen other questions, but they don't seem to fit my particular case.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can read a JSON file and store it in a MATLAB structure using the following command `structure1 = matlab.internal.webservices.fromJSON(json_string)`

You can create a JSON string from a MATLAB structure using the following command `json_string= matlab.internal.webservices.toJSON(structure1)`

Answer (score -1):

[JSONlab](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab--a-toolbox-to-encode-decode-json-files?requestedDomain=true) is what you want. It has a 'loadjson' function which inputs a char array of JSON data and returns a struct with all the data